# CSS background not showing IE 8 and earlier

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, background, internet-explorer-8

My problem here is, that my background loads perfectly fine in almost all browsers except for IE8 and below. 
The page can be seen here: [http://www.glnyrupvej.co.nf/](http://www.glnyrupvej.co.nf)
Here is a screenshot of the page in IE8: [Page in IE8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Jelj.jpg)

Here is my CSS:

```
height: 700px;
padding-top: 50px;
background: url(images/fraluften.png) no-repeat center center fixed;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
```

Yes, i do realize that there is other questions like this, but none of them could help me.

This is probably something super basic that i just overlooked, so answers is appreciated! (:

Comment: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: if it is not a strict demand from a client, don't try to make your site compatible with IE Napoleon-edition (IE8-). IE8 died with windows XP in the spring of 2014 (thank god!). Most developers/companies do not support it anymore, and users should never-ever use versions prior to 9, considering no updates at all (security or others) are released by MS.

Comment: @abhijith, useless comment... your tutorial says literally "Works in: IE9+"

Comment: @JasonvanderZeeuw Would you mind to read it again pls?? it says **background-size:cover;** supported bY
Safari 3+
Chrome Whatever+
IE 9+
Opera 10+ (Opera 9.5 supported background-size but not the keywords)
Firefox 3.6+ (Firefox 4 supports non-vendor prefixed version)

But there are some other tweaks that _may_ work

Comment: @JasonvanderZeeuw The client i am working for is using IE8, so i guess enabling IE8 support is easier than teaching her how to update her browser.
Thanks for the comment though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**background-size: cover;** is a **css3** property so it will **not work** in IE8 or earlier versions.Better try to achieve it using **image tag** like this:

**Your header html code**

```
    <header>
            <center>
    <img src="images/fraluften.png" class="backgroundClass">
<img src="images/scrolldownB.png" id="scrolldownB" style="display: inline;">
            </center>
            </header>
```

**CSS for backgroundClass**

```
.backgroundClass{
    display: inline;
    height: 700px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    }
```

Comment: I guess this is as good as it gets. It is definitely not the same effect as background-size: cover;, but at least my image shows up now.

Thanks buddy.